# Access - Delete a record with an attachment field

Tags: ms-access, attachment, record

I have a continuous form with various records from a table.  The table has about 5 fields and one of them contains attachments.  The attachment is not displayed on the form.

When I create (and use) a delete button, I get a message that I am about to delete one record and I proceed.  The record appears to have deleted as it is removed from the form.  However it is not deleted as it returns when it is refreshed or reopened.  Instead, however the attachment that is stored in the attachment field is deleted.  (I am using Access 2016)

I have tried using the automated delete record button which creates a macro.
I have also tried using the following code but get the same results.

```
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

'If MsgBox("Are you sure you wish to delete this record?" & vbCrLf & "It cannot be undone?", vbYesNo + vbInformation, "Please confirm:") = vbYes Then
    'Set rst = Me.Recordset
    'If Not rst.EOF Then
        'rst.Delete
        'rst.MoveNext
    'End If


     'set rst = Nothing
'End If
```

Also tried

```
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdDeleteRecord
```

and get the same results.  The record appears deleted as it is removed from the form.  The record is returned upon refresh or reopening the form.  The document is deleted from the field which contains attachments.  Note that in all cases there is only one attachment in the field.

Comment: I didn't state this above, but my goal is to delete the entire record.

Comment: Another piece of information that may be helpful.  -- When I delete the record, I stated the record disappears from my form.  When I refresh, it reappears, if i try to delete again, I get "no current record."  However if I close and reopen the form, the record is there (attachment deleted) and I can attempt to delete it again as I do not get the message "no current record."  But does not delete, only disappears from the form as stated above.

Comment: I added --  Debug.Print rst!ID, rst!A_Name to the code and got expected results that I am on the correct record.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same issue with Access 2013 and I suspect the same would apply to Access 2016, but I have no way of testing. I had a subform which contained 2-3 fields plus an attachment. When I deleted the row in the form, it removed the row from the form, but upon Refresh the row returned.

On looking at the properties of my Form, the **Record Source** was set to

```
SELECT * from Attachment
```

Updating this to just "Attachment" fixed the issue

It seems that Access can't delete the row when the data source is set to a query rather than being linked to the actual table.